# JAVA: Why is my update of the ArrayList value of a specific key in a Hashmap changing all the other key values?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'd need your help because I have no idea why my update of a value (for a specific key) in a hashmap is changing almost all the other keys'value...
Here's the corresponding code that you can try out:

```
import edu.duke.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordsInFiles {
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList> map;

    public WordsInFiles(){
        map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();
    }

    private void addWordsFromFile(File f) {
        FileResource fr = new FileResource(f);
        String fileName = f.getName();
        ArrayList<String> newWord = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : fr.words()){
            if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
                newWord.clear();
                newWord.add(fileName);
                map.put(s, newWord);
                System.out.println("New:" + s + "\t" + newWord);
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> currArr = map.get(s);
                if (!currArr.contains(fileName)){
                    currArr.add(fileName);
                    newWord = currArr;
                    System.out.println("Update:" +s + "\t" + newWord);
                    map.put(s, newWord);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(map + "\n");
        }
    }

    public void tester() {
        System.out.println("\n ****** New Tester Instance ****** ");
        buildWordFileMap();
    }
}
```

By running tester on 4 files: brief1.txt, brief2.txt, brief3.txt and brief4.txt that respectively contains the strings:

1. cats are funny and cute
2. dogs are silly
3. love animals cats and dogs
4. love birds and cats

I get:

```
 ****** New Tester Instance ****** 
New:cats    [brief1.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt]}

New:are [brief1.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt], are=[brief1.txt]}

New:funny   [brief1.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt], are=[brief1.txt], funny=[brief1.txt]}

New:and [brief1.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt], are=[brief1.txt], and=[brief1.txt], funny=[brief1.txt]}

New:cute    [brief1.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt], are=[brief1.txt], and=[brief1.txt], cute=[brief1.txt], funny=[brief1.txt]}

New:dogs    [brief2.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt], are=[brief1.txt], and=[brief1.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], cute=[brief1.txt], funny=[brief1.txt]}

Update:are  [brief1.txt, brief2.txt]
{cats=[brief1.txt, brief2.txt], are=[brief1.txt, brief2.txt], and=[brief1.txt, brief2.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], cute=[brief1.txt, brief2.txt], funny=[brief1.txt, brief2.txt]}

New:silly   [brief2.txt]
{cats=[brief2.txt], are=[brief2.txt], and=[brief2.txt], silly=[brief2.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], cute=[brief2.txt], funny=[brief2.txt]}

New:love    [brief3.txt]
{love=[brief3.txt], cats=[brief2.txt], are=[brief2.txt], and=[brief2.txt], silly=[brief2.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], cute=[brief2.txt], funny=[brief2.txt]}

New:animals [brief3.txt]
{love=[brief3.txt], cats=[brief2.txt], are=[brief2.txt], and=[brief2.txt], silly=[brief2.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], animals=[brief3.txt], cute=[brief2.txt], funny=[brief2.txt]}

Update:cats [brief2.txt, brief3.txt]
{love=[brief3.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], animals=[brief3.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt]}

{love=[brief3.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt], animals=[brief3.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt]}

Update:dogs [brief2.txt, brief3.txt]
{love=[brief3.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], animals=[brief3.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt]}

Update:love [brief3.txt, brief4.txt]
{love=[brief3.txt, brief4.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], animals=[brief3.txt, brief4.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt]}

New:birds   [brief4.txt]
{love=[brief4.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], animals=[brief4.txt], birds=[brief4.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt]}

Update:and  [brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt]
{love=[brief4.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], animals=[brief4.txt], birds=[brief4.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt]}

{love=[brief4.txt], cats=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], are=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], and=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], silly=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], dogs=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt], animals=[brief4.txt], birds=[brief4.txt], cute=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt], funny=[brief2.txt, brief3.txt, brief4.txt]}
```

And I really don't get why on the line "Update:are  [brief1.txt, brief2.txt]" the code updates all the keys of map for this ArrayList value. And even though it would be updating all the keys'value: Why all the keys except for dogs?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Because you keep putting the same `ArrayList` instance into the map.

Comment: Isn't the ArrayList constantly updated by 'ArrayList<String> currArr = map.get(s);'

Comment: Look all the answer before accepting ;) I gave you some tips to improve your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you keep putting the same `ArrayList` instance into the map.

After

```
map.put(s, newWord);
```

write:

```
newWord = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or, better, just declare `newWord` inside that block:

```
List<String> newWord = new ArrayList<>();
newWord.add(fileName);
map.put(s, newWord);
```

Or, in one line:

```
map.put(s, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fileName));
```

But I would suggest that your "lists" are actually `Set`s, since you are only adding them if they are not already present. If you want an order-preserving set, use `LinkedHashSet` as your value type.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Andy! I will accept the answer but I have to wait 9 mins... Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You created the `newWord` once and then keep **putting** the same `List` to the `map`.

```
ArrayList<String> newWord = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Within the `loop`, you put it in as:

```
        if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
            newWord.clear();
            newWord.add(fileName);
            map.put(s, newWord); // your problem lies here
            // created just once but put in many times;
            System.out.println("New:" + s + "\t" + newWord);
        }
```

You can replace that line with

```
map.put(s, new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Correct**

The `newWord` you put in you map is always the same instance, so every keys have the same `list` as value, you change it and you see it everywhere, you need to put a new `list` each time :

```
for (String s : fr.words()){
    if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
        ArrayList<String> newWord = new ArrayList<>();         
        newWord.add(fileName);
        map.put(s, newWord);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> currArr = map.get(s);
        if (!currArr.contains(fileName)){
            currArr.add(fileName);                            
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2.Improve**

- don't use raw types, use generics : `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, and when you create it you can simply use `map = new HashMap<>`
- use `Set` instead of `List`, it'll automaticlly avoid duplicate and you won't have to check if the `filename` is already present before `add`
- the first `if` does `check & add`, and the `else` does `add`, you may simplify in an `check` part then always `add`. And for the `check` part you can check and put at the same time with `putIfAbsent()` method from `Map`

---

**3.Shorten**

1. `computeIfAbsent` will try to get the value from the key and if there is not it'll insert it with a new `HashSet`.
2. the value if returned and ready to be used (the value is the `HashSet`)
3. just `add` the filename to this value, no need to check because we're using `Set` and no duplicate is possible

```
// map is now a HashMap<String, Set<String>>
for (String s : fr.words()){
    map.computeIfAbsent(s, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(filename);
}
```